# Connecting Azure Web App to Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm considering Reliable Actors right now that's part of Service Fabric. I have an existing Web App that I'd like to keep and act as an API surface to my actors. The Web App will also handle authentication and authorization before any calls get to my actors.

I can't tell from the documentation, but is it possible to connect a Web App to Service Fabric? Additionally, is it possible to limit connections to Service Fabric so that it doesn't except any public connections? How would I go about setting this up, or is it even advisable to do something like this?

I know with Cloud Services, you can connect a Cloud Service to a Web App through a Virtual Network, so I'm at least familiar with that kind of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it the same way you do with cloud services - use a virtual network.  Service Fabric is just a framework running on VMs in a cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

Connection to the service fabric can be controlled through the loadbalancers in the cluster VNET. I would suggest that you integrate the WebApp into the Service fabric cluster VNET, to do that you will have to add a VNET gateway